# Validating that a user is still a valid user in a Google Workspace following a sign in

Tags: google-oauth, single-sign-on, openid-connect, google-signin

I'm trying to build a system that allows users to authenticate with Google, using the frontend [Sign In with Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) based on OpenID Connect. I do not want or need to be authorised to access any Google services; the purpose of the Google integration here is *solely* authentication.

Once authenticated with Google, we exchange the ID JWT that Google issues to the frontend for an app-specific short-lived access token from the app's backend. However, when refreshing that access token, we need to check that the user is still authenticatable at Google. This is important because the user could be in a Google Workspace directory, and if they are, if they are removed from the directory or their account is disabled we need to not allow them to reauthenticate.

My ideal implementation idea for this would be simply to not issue those users refresh tokens, and allow them to authenticate again and get a new access token for so long as they have a valid Google ID JWT. However, the Sign In with Google APIs do not appear to have functionality to allow you to request another authentication moment, or to get a new ID token, beyond the initial time that it happens. As a consequence, that limits the total session time to one hour (or whatever Google decides at any stage to change their JWT expiry to).

Is there any way around this other than unnecessarily turning the application's backend into a full OAuth client with an access token for the user? That seems a less-than-ideal solution on the grounds of keeping to the least-privilege principle, keeping as few requests as possible involved in these transactions, and maintainability and simplicity of code.